# Django form.save(commit=False) not adding user_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to add created by whoever is logged in user but not getting that saved even though I am logged in. `form.created_by = request.user` is not adding logged in user.

```
def create_table_allotment(request):
    form = TableAllotmentForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {'form': form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save(commit=False)
                form.created_by = request.user
                form.save()
                return redirect('order_management:table_allotment_home')
            except IntegrityError as err:
                print('err => ', err)
                context['unique_error'] = 'User has already assigned table for today'

    return render(request, 'orders/table_allotment/create.html', context)
```

Here are my models

```
class QOTs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "QOTs"


class TableAllotment(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    qot = models.ForeignKey(QOTs, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    club = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='POS-0001')
    from_table = models.IntegerField()
    to_table = models.IntegerField()
    working_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='qot_creator')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created at"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Updated at"), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id',)
        unique_together = ('employee', 'working_date',)
```

Here is my form

```
class TableAllotmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TableAllotment
        fields = ["employee", "qot", "from_table", "to_table"]
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form.save(commit=False)` will return the instance wrapped by the form which you can then modify and call `save` on. Instead you are just calling save on the `form` again and also you are setting `form.created_by = request.user` i.e. you are setting an attribute on the form.

Instead you should directly modify the `instance` wrapped by the form:

```
def create_table_allotment(request):
    form = TableAllotmentForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {'form': form}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.instance.created_by = request.user
                form.save()
                return redirect('order_management:table_allotment_home')
            except IntegrityError as err:
                print('err => ', err)
                context['unique_error'] = 'User has already assigned table for today'

    return render(request, 'orders/table_allotment/create.html', context)
```

> **Note**: `TableAllotmentForm(request.POST or None)` is an anti-pattern (It is possible for an empty form to be valid in certain conditions) and you should simply pass `request.POST` only if
> `request.method == "POST"` else you should simply write
> `TableAllotmentForm()`.

Comment: Thank You Abdul Aziz Barkat you are a lifesaver, highly appreciated.

Comment: @MuhammadSharif also I noticed that you use that try-except to prevent those integrity errors? Perhaps this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66954768/manually-set-model-fields-in-modelform/66954859#66954859) might be helpful to you, it is on making the form itself validate the unique constraints.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to what Abdul Aziz Barkat has suggested would be to assign returned object of [**`save()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)([Django-Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)) method like so `obj = form.save(commit=False)`.

I would also add `@login_required` to the view

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def create_table_allotment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TableAllotmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                obj.created_by = request.user
                obj.save()
                return redirect('order_management:table_allotment_home')
            except IntegrityError as err:
                print('err => ', err)
                context['unique_error'] = 'User has already assigned table for today'
    else:
        form = TableAllotmentForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'orders/table_allotment/create.html', context)
```